# Position absolute inside a scrolling overflow container

Tags: html, css, position

I have the following code:

```css
.chat-content {
  height: 455px;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #cacac8;
}

.chat-content,
.chat-content-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.chat-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-buttons {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #dddddb;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0
}

.top-buttons .badge {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.top-buttons .badge:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: -5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
  border-color: transparent #999;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.top-buttons h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #858689
}

.chat-pusher {
  position: relative;
}


/*Styling Chat Sidebar Menu*/

.chat-users-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -110px;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #858689;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  overflow-y: auto;
}


/*Toggle Class for Moving Chat Menu Users*/

.chatbar-toggle {
  left: 0;
}


/*/Toggle Class for Moving Chat Menu Users*/

.chat-users-menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.chat-users-menu .menu-header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.chat-users-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 15px 90px 10px 10px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-transition: background .3s, box-shadow .3s;
  transition: background .3s, box-shadow .3s;
}

.chat-users-menu ul li a .chat-name {
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1.05em;
}

.chat-users-menu ul li a .badge {
  position: absolute;
  background: #d24d33;
  color: #fff;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.chat-users-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.chat-users-menu ul li a .label {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.chat-users-menu ul li .user-img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 40px;
}

.chat-users-menu ul li .user-img img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #fff;
}


/* And finally! Messages List and Chat Contents */

.chat-messages {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.chat-messages-with-sidebar {
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.chat-messages ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.chat-messages li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.chat-messages li.left .chat-body {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.chat-messages li.left .chat-body :before {
  /*content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 20%;
 left: -7px;
 border-style: solid;*/
  border-width: 6px 7px 6px 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff;
  /*display: block;
 width: 0;*/
}

.chat-messages li.right .chat-body {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 70px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.chat-messages li.right .chat-body :after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: -7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px 0 6px 7px;
  border-color: transparent #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
}

.chat-messages .badge {
  font-size: .85em;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #c0c2c7;
}

.chat-messages .chat-body .name {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.chat-messages .user-img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 45px;
}

.chat-messages .user-img img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px #fff;
}

.chat-message-form {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #dddddb;
  display: block
}

.nano {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nano>.nano-content {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nano>.nano-content:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}

.nano>.nano-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.has-scrollbar>.nano-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  visibility: visible;
}

.nano>.nano-pane {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  visibility: hidden\9;
  /* Target only IE7 and IE8 with this hack */
  opacity: .01;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  -moz-transition: .2s;
  -o-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}

.nano>.nano-pane>.nano-slider {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.nano:hover>.nano-pane,
.nano-pane.active,
.nano-pane.flashed {
  visibility: visible\9;
  /* Target only IE7 and IE8 with this hack */
  opacity: 0.99;
}

.msg-is-typing-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-container">
  <div class="chat-pusher">
    <div class="chat-content">
      <!-- this is the wrapper for the content -->
      <div class="nano">
        <!-- this is the nanoscroller -->
        <div class="nano-content">
          <div class="">
            <!-- extra div for emulating position:fixed of the menu -->
            <!-- Top Navigation -->
            <div class="">
              <div class="chat-messages chat-messages-with-sidebar">
                <ul id="thread-msg-content" data-msg-thread-id="">


                  <li class="left clearfix">
                    <div class="user-img pull-left">
                      <img src="http://www.simpsonspark.com/images/persos/contributions/bart-simpson-20516.gif" alt="User Avatar" width="50" height="50" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                      <div class="header"> <span class="name"><a href="#">Administrator</a></span><span class="name"></span> <span class="badge"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>2018-06-21 04:38:44</span> …
                        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                          <p>fdfdffdfddfd</p>
                        </div>
                  </li>

                  <li class="left clearfix">
                    <div class="user-img pull-left">
                      <img src="http://www.simpsonspark.com/images/persos/contributions/bart-simpson-20516.gif" alt="User Avatar" width="50" height="50" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                      <div class="header"> <span class="name"><a href="#">Administrator</a></span><span class="name"></span> <span class="badge"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>2018-06-21 04:38:44</span> …
                        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                          <p>fdfdffdfddfd</p>
                        </div>
                  </li>

                  <li class="left clearfix">
                    <div class="user-img pull-left">
                      <img src="http://www.simpsonspark.com/images/persos/contributions/bart-simpson-20516.gif" alt="User Avatar" width="50" height="50" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                      <div class="header"> <span class="name"><a href="#">Administrator</a></span><span class="name"></span> <span class="badge"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>2018-06-21 04:38:44</span> …
                        <div class="chat-body clearfix">
                          <p>fdfdffdfddfd</p>
                        </div>
                  </li>

                </ul>

                <div class="msg-is-typing-container">
                  <p class="msg-is-typing">Administrator is typing ...</p>
                </div>

                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /chat-content-inner -->
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /nano -->
                </div>
                <!-- /chat-content -->
              </div>
              <!-- /chat-pusher -->
            </div>
```

Result I want: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3438835/f249eeacac535cd7715d72d9c3b1dcb4

I want to show div ".msg-is-typing-container" to the bottom of the container ".chat-content", but when the scroll bar is shown the div ".msg-is-typing-container" is not displayed at the bottom of the container.

How to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: why position it absolutely if you want it at the bottom of the div?

Comment: Yeah I agree with @Pete on this. Why give the element position absolute in the first place?

Comment: I use absolute position Because I want  ".msg-is-typing-container" class be at the bottom to the container ".chat-content"

Comment: Are you wanting the message to be at the bottom of the visible portion of the div at all times? Because that would be `position: fixed;`

Comment: @MappyLord, if you want it at the bottom of the chat-container, why not move it to where `<!-- /chat-pusher -->` is and just position it relatively?

Comment: Not chat-container but chat-content

Comment: then my original comment stands why absolute - if you use relative, it will be at the bottom of it anyway.  If you want it at the bottom of the chat-content but always visible, then you need to use sticky (not advisable as it is still experimental) or change the layout so that bit is not part of the overflowing content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I altered `.msg-is-typing-container`'s CSS to achieve the positioning I believe you want.

```
.msg-is-typing-container{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

I then added a matching id as shown to this element: `<p class="msg-is-typing" id="msg-is-typing"></p>`

The below jQuery & JavaScript hides the typing container `.msg-is-typing-container` until the `.nano-content` container is scrolled to the bottom, at which time the container fades into view. I also added a JavaScript typing effect [found here at w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_typewriter). You can see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8o0h6xv/86/) where I tried to answer the question as I understood it.

```
$('.msg-is-typing-container').hide();

$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var txt = 'Administrator is typing ...And Only Shows when div is scolled to bottom';
  var speed = 100;                

  function typeWriter() {
    if (i < txt.length ) {
      document.getElementById("msg-is-typing").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
      i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }
  }    


  $(".nano-content").scroll(function(){   
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0) {
      $('.msg-is-typing-container').fadeIn(2000);

    }
    else{
      $('.msg-is-typing-container').fadeOut(1000);
    }
  })

  typeWriter();
})
```

Comment: jQuery's animations operate on a queue - if you rapidly scroll up and down to the bottom a few times and then sit at the bottom, you'll get to watch that message fade in and out a bunch of times. To counteract this you should call `.stop()` before the animation calls - like `$('element').stop().fadeIn(2000);`

Answer (score 1):

```
.chat-messages {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
}
.msg-is-typing-container{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-25px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot in the answer above, is there a difference between what you are looking for?

Comment: Leave only one "li" element and you'll see ".msg-is-typing-container" is not at the bottom of the container ".chat-content"

Comment: Sorry, but why upload a screenshot of code, why not just make a working snippet?

Comment: The code snippet is in the original answer... it can be copy pasted into the jsfiddle ...the screenshot is to show the output and to get clarification if there is a difference from the original question.